# LUA: Reading text after reading number does not work

Tags: text, lua, numbers

I am struck with the io.read command in LUA. The example below jumps over the text-read line. That only happens if there is a number input before.

```
repeat
  print("Input number!")
  number=io.read("*n")
  print("Would you like do to this again? (y/n)")
  again = io.read()
until again == "n"
```

I tried this in two IDEs (repl and ZeroBrane) and it drives me MAAAD!!!

Cany anyone help, please?

Cheers,

Ulrich

Comment: Try `number=io.read("*n", "*l")`

Comment: Nope! Line-Parameter is default anyway and then you just have more waits for RETURN!

Comment: What is “more waits for RETURN” even supposed to mean?  The solution proposed by @EgorSkriptunoff works perfectly for the example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading line by line as string and convert string to number using tonumber()

```
repeat
        print("Input number!")
        num = tonumber(io.read())    
        print('Would you like do to this again? (y/n)')
        again = io.read()
until again == 'n'
```

While debugging, I see that second io.read is using the buffer started just after your number ends.

Your code with some more prints

```
repeat
    print("Input number!")
    -- num = tonumber(io.read())
    num = io.read('*n')
    print('you entered-> ' .. tostring(num))

    print('Would you like do to this again? (y/n)')
    again = io.read()
    print('your choise from (y/n)-> ' .. again)
until again == 'n'
```

output

```
Input number!
234
you entered-> 234
Would you like do to this again? (y/n)
your choise from (y/n)->
Input number!
234y
you entered-> 234
Would you like do to this again? (y/n)
your choise from (y/n)-> y
Input number!
234234n
you entered-> 234234
Would you like do to this again? (y/n)
your choise from (y/n)-> n
```

This description is from  [Programming in Lua: 21.1](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html)

> The call io.read("*number") reads a number from the current input file. This is the only case where read returns a number, instead of a string. When you need to read many numbers from a file, the absence of the intermediate strings can make a significant performance improvement. The *number option skips any spaces before the number and accepts number formats like -3, +5.2, 1000, and -3.4e-23. If it cannot find a number at the current file position (because of bad format or end of file), it returns nil.

Please apologize for the poor description.